# Inconsistent requirement of Model prefix for asp.net core tag helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I noticed a strange behavior in which there is inconsistent requirement of  `Model` prefix for asp.net core tag helpers below. `asp-for` cannot accept `Model` prefix but `asp-items` must have `Model` prefix. My head explodes.

```
@model ProblemVM
<select 
     asp-for="Problem.TagId"
     asp-items="Model.Tags.ToSelectListItem(Model.Problem.TagId)"
/>

public class ProblemVM
{
    public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public Problem Problem{ get; set; }
}
```

Related classes.

```
public abstract class ISelectListItemable
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Tag: ISelectListItemable
{

    [Display(Name = "Tag Name")]
    public override string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Problem : ISelectListItemable
{
    [Display(Name = "Problem Name")]
    public override string Name { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(TagId))]
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItem<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int selectedValue)
        where T : ISelectListItemable

    {
        return from item in items
               select new SelectListItem
               {
                   Text = item.Name,
                   Value = item.Id.ToString(),
                   Selected = item.Id.Equals(selectedValue)
               };
    }
```

## Question

What is the rule of using `Model` prefix for tag helpers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2#the-select-tag-helper) does say that:

> The `asp-for` attribute value is a special case and doesn't require a Model prefix, the other Tag Helper attributes do (such as `asp-items`)

The reason I see is that `asp-for` will *always* be from your model. But `asp-items` can be *any* collection. It doesn't have to be from your model. So if you do want it to be from your model, you need to tell it that.

Answer (score 2):

It's about the actual type of the property the attribute of the tag helper corresponds to. The `asp-for` attribute maps to a `For` property on the built-in tag helpers which is typed as `ModelExpression`. So, it literally is looking for an expression relative to the model of the view.

The `asp-items` attribute, on the other hand is typed as `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, and thus literally needs a concrete value, not just an expression. The fact that it just so happens to be coming from a prop on your model is inconsequential. The value could come from `ViewData`, or be satisfied directly inline.

There are certain situations, though, when you still need to include `Model` for an attribute like `asp-for`. This is generally when your model itself is a list, dictionary, etc. and you need to index. You can't just add something like `[i].Foo` as an expression, so in that case you would do `@Model[i].Foo`.